# Why do these properties determine this map up to an additive constant?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

In Ahlfors' text, he considers a region $\Omega$ bounded by analytic contours $C_1, \dots, C_n$.

On page 259 he states:

> We have thus established the existence of a function $p(z)$ which is single-valued and analytic in $\Omega$, except for a simple pole with the residue $1$ at $z_0$, and whose real part is constant on each contour. *By these requirements $p(z)$ is uniquely determined up to an additive constant.*

I can't see how do the requirements determine $p(z)$: If $p_1(z)$ is another function with these properties, we have that $p-p_1$ has no singular part, and still has its real part constant on each contour. I can't see why this difference must reduce to a constant though.

Could you please help me see why it is the case?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I went out there and read but I have no idea.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva thanks for the attempt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides other things, the function $p$ is continuous on $\overline{\Omega}$. If $p_1$ is another one such, and $f:=p-p_1$ is nonconstant, then $f(\Omega)$ is a bounded domain. By the open mapping theorem $\partial f(\Omega)\subset f(\partial \Omega)$. But the values that $f$ takes on $\partial \Omega$ lie on a finite union of vertical lines. Being open,   $ f(\Omega)$  contains a point $w$ which is not on any of those lines. The vertical line through $w$ does not meet $\partial f(\Omega)$, which contradicts  the latter being bounded.